# Remove randomly selected purchases that have been copied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame. I would like to split the amount of purchases of `AMOUNT_` randomly from this data frame and add it to a new data frame and delete this line from the old one.
If `AMOUNT_ = 2`, then two purchases should be randomly selected, copied out and then removed.

Below you can see how it should work. The problem is this code is very slow. Now my question is how can I solve this better and make the code faster?

```
d = {'purchaseid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
     'itemid': [ 3, 8, 2, 10, 3, 10, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 12, 9, 9, 13, 1, 7, 11, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


AMOUNT_= 2

def splitter(df):
  df_ = pd.DataFrame()
  sum_purchase = df['purchaseid'].nunique()
  amount = AMOUNT_

  list_purchase = []
  while len(list_purchase) < amount:
    choose = random.choice(df['purchaseid'])
    if choose not in list_purchase:
      list_purchase.append(choose)  

  for i in list_purchase:
    df_item = df.loc[lambda df: df['purchaseid'] == i]
    df = df[df.purchaseid != i]
    df_ = pd.concat([df_, df_item])
  print('Splitted {0} purchase'.format(df_['purchaseid'].nunique()))
  return [df, df_]


dfs = splitter(df)
df_fr = dfs[0].copy(deep=True)
print(df_fr)
print(dfs[1])
```

Output:

```
[OUT]
df1

    purchaseid  itemid
0            0       3
1            0       8
2            0       2
3            1      10
4            2       3
5            2      10
9            4      12
10           4       3
11           4       4
12           5       8
13           5       6
14           5       3
15           6       0
16           6       5
17           6      12
18           7       9
19           7       9
20           8      13

df2

    purchaseid  itemid
21           9       1
22           9       7
23           9      11
24           9      11
6            3       4
7            3      12
8            3       3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more concise and saves you some time. Note the use of ~ to reduce/filter the original dataframe

```
def splitter(df, amount):  
  random_list = random.sample(df['purchaseid'].unique().tolist(), amount)
  df_ = df.loc[df['purchaseid'].isin(random_list)]
  df_reduced = df.loc[~df['purchaseid'].isin(random_list)]
  return [df_reduced, df_]

#use ipython %timeit
%timeit dfs = splitter(df, AMOUNT_)
1.2 ms ± 2.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
vs original code
1.97 ms ± 10 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks! From 21 min to 1 sek! Thanks a lot! :)